# Getting Data from a tableview and store to sqlite database

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsarray

I Have a form with Tableview and Custom Cells with many number of text fields,Label and textViews.If a user Fills All fields and He want to save the Form then How can i get all the field values on my Button click method ?

I would highly appreciate it if someone could help me out by showing me how to do this.

Comment: Are you creating these dynamically in your cellAtIndexPath function?

Comment: @rooster117  Thanks for Your response, actually user will insert data into respective fields at run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't wait until the button click event to retrieve the cell contents. Because cells are reused (e.g., during scrolling), the values in each cell will not be preserved.

As cell values change, update the model that drives your table by making the tableViewController a delegate for the respective input fields.

For example, make the tableViewController the textField delegate and update the model as the user inputs data. To distinguish among textFields in the tableViewController, assign a tag to each textField when creating the cell (i.e., tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath).

Answer (score 1):

// get the path of cell from row and section

```
-(void)btnClick
{
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    customTxtField *cellCustomTxtField  = (customTxtField *)[mytableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
    NSString *str =  cellCustomTxtField.text1.text;
}
```